# Redirect during the script execution

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have to test a web site, and I have wrote a `tampermonkey` script that surf randomly the site and change parameters, sometimes I need to change page and if I change page with `window.location.replace(URL)` or by pressing button with the script, for example `document.getElementById('button_that_redirects').click()` the script stop to works after the new page is loaded.
How can I do to run a `javascript` script that allow to change page during the execution? Have I to use an other program instead tampermonkey?

Comment: tampermonkey scripts are created to run on particular pages (exact match, or pattern match) - if you are not on a page that matches one of the `include` patterns in the script, the script wont run

Comment: And which program can I use to do this?

Comment: @Andrea993 - write an web extension / chrome add-on / whatever google call it

Answer (score 0):

If you have redirections happening on the same domain, you could let your script create a cookie with all necessary state information, so that when the script gets launched on the redirected page, your script can detect the cookie, get the necessary context from it, and continue with whatever it needs to do. You could for instance include [js_cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for this.

An alternative to using cookies would be an [`html5` local database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage).